# Temporarily change the xfce4-terminal title from within the terminal

Tags: debian, terminal, xfce, xfce4-terminal

How can I change the title of the `xfce4-terminal` (0.6.3) window, from within the terminal for the current session?

I can change the title by using the Menu bar `Terminal`, then `Set Title...`.

I've tried the following, which I found while researching the matter, but none of them worked:

```
echo -ne "\033]0;SOME TITLE HERE\007"

printf '\033]0;%s\007' 'SOME TITLE HERE'

export TERM='SOME TITLE HERE'

xtermset -T 'SOME TITLE HERE'
```

The solution states in the similar questions does not seem to work in my case.

Comment: The 1st, 2nd and 4th versions are correct. The only problem with them is probably that immediately after they set the title the shell prompt is displayed again which resets it. Check your `PS1` and `PROMPT_COMMAND` variables do make sure this is the case. I don't know where you found the 3rd version, it's horribly broken, it does not set the title at all and breaks plenty of apps.

Comment: So how do I prevent the reset and make the change for the current terminal session?

Comment: You need to define the `PS1` and/or `PROMPT_COMMAND` variables in your `.profile` or `.bashrc` in a way that they do not alter the terminal title.

Comment: the point IS to alter the terminal title, so your telling me define it to alter but in a way that they dont alter it. what?

Answer (score 4):

I have been able to change the title using this command:

`PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;SOME TITLE HERE\007";'`

Unfortunately, in my tests with xfce4-terminal, this only changes part of the title. So the new title is:

```
Terminal - SOME TITLE HERE
```

I'm guessing this is not the behavior you desire but it is probably as close as you will get with xfce4-terminal. This methods works perfectly fine with urxvt.

Comment: that doesn't work for me, what version of xfce4-terminal do you use?

Comment: I ran this test using version 0.6.3 on Arch Linux.

Comment: That's weird. I'm on Debian Stretch with xfce4-terminal 0.6.3 and the title doesn't change at all with the above `echo` command.

Comment: Regarding the "Terminal - TITLE", xfce-terminal (at least for >= 0.8) has Edit->Preferences->General->Title->Dynamically-set title->Replaces initial title.

Comment: try PS1 instead of `PROMPT_COMMAND`